# Converting strings into binary data in perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to convert a "string" which is filled with values from "\x00" to "\xFF" and I would like to know if a special bit is set in a special byte in the string. Therefore I created a small function but it does not work:

```
 sub isBitSetInCtrMsg
 {
     my $data              = shift;   # value can be: "\xFF"
     my $data_byte_address = shift;   # value can be 0-88
     my $data_bit_address  = shift;   # value can be 0-7

     my @data_array = split('',$data);   #"split string into bytes"

     my $data_byte = $data_array[$data_byte_address];   # pick specific byte

     $is_set = ($data_byte & (1 << $data_bit_address)); # check if bit is set

     return $is_set;                                    # return value
 }
```

I thought it was quit a simple part of my code but the problem is if `$data = 0xFF` then everything works fine, but if my data is `\xFF` my code doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me why and how can I check this in the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Perl is magic when it comes to handling scalars. It decides on the fly how to 'handle' it.

How is the value passed into this subroutine? Because I think that's where your thing might be breaking.

Consider:

```
print 0xFF,"\n";
print "\xFF","\n";
print '\xFF',"\n";
```

In each case, perl's figuring out how to treat the string you've handed it. There's every chance that if you're passing it '\xFF' it's deciding that's 4 separate bytes, which'll be where your problem comes in.

Try adding:

```
use Data::Dumper;
```

And in your sub (before assigning):

```
print Dumper \@_;
```